# Codeigniter pagination create_link() method is not showing any links

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

Here is my controller code. I am confused with the base_url, don't know where whether the following URL is write or wrong.

```
Public function index(){

    $this->load->library('pagination');
    //setting value for pagination      

    $config['base_url'] = base_url()."/index.php/products/index";
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->Product_model->record_count();
    $config['per_page'] = 10;
    $config['num_links'] = 20;      
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);


    $data['products'] = $this->Product_model->get_products('productid','DESC', $config["per_page"], $this->uri->segment(3));

    //Load View
    $data['main_content'] = 'products';
    $this->load->view('layouts/main', $data);

}
```

and view code

```
<div id="pagination">
    <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links();?>
</div>
```

Comment: Show your routes for that page you may need to do `$route['yourpage/(:any)'] = "controllername/$1"`

Comment: Show model function as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your pagination check your routes.php But not much to go on by your code
You did not show your model functions for get products.

```
$route['products'] = "product/index"
$route['products/(:any)'] = "product/index/$1";
```

Try This

```
public function index(){

// Load your model
$this->load->model('product_model');

// Load Pagination Library
$this->load->library('pagination');      

// Uri segment would be 2
$config['base_url'] = base_url('products');

// Or 

//Uri segment would be 2
// $config['base_url'] = base_url('index.php/products'); 

$config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('products');
$config['per_page'] = 10;
$config['num_links'] = 20;      
$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
$config['uri_segment'] = 2;

// If use bootstrap or else remove.
$config['full_tag_open'] = "<ul class='pagination'>";
$config['full_tag_close'] ="</ul>";
$config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['cur_tag_open'] = "<li class='disabled'><li class='active'><a href='#'>";
$config['cur_tag_close'] = "<span class='sr-only'></span></a></li>";
$config['next_tag_open'] = "<li>";
$config['next_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
$config['prev_tag_open'] = "<li>";
$config['prev_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
$config['first_tag_open'] = "<li>";
$config['first_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
$config['last_tag_open'] = "<li>";
$config['last_tagl_close'] = "</li>";

$this->pagination->initialize($config);

// Removed DESC
$data['products'] = $this->product_model->get_products('productid', $config["per_page"], $config['uri_segment']); 
$data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

//Load View
$data['main_content'] = 'products';
$this->load->view('layouts/main', $data);

}
```

**View**

```
<div id="pagination">
    <?php echo $pagination;?>
</div>
```

Comment: my routes;
             $route['default_controller'] = "products";


          $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:90/oshop/';